# Google maps api javascript tag not validating

Tags: javascript, validation, google-maps-api-3

Looking at getting a current website site am working on fully HTML5 validated using W3C

This is the Google map API Javascript tag that is failing to validate.

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
```

This is the response from W3C

> & did not start a character reference. (& probably should have been escaped as &.)

It does not like the `&` when defining if the sensor is true or false.

I have tried the following

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&ampsensor=false"></script>
```

When running the page i get a Error from the API explaining i have not used &sensor and it needs to be set to true or false.

Anyone have any ideas how to overcome this please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just have forgotten to put a semicolon behind the `&amp;`

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&amp;sensor=false"></script>
```

should work

Comment: Thank you! That is correct I have not idea how I missed that.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
```

So you need to get the API_KEY from [here](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=devconsole&passive=1209600&continue=https://code.google.com/apis/console/&followup=https://code.google.com/apis/console/) first.