# W3C doesn't validate google maps api

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

right now im working on going through the html to validate and correct anything that's not right, so i've come to this problem:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
```

as it is, everything works fine, but it doesnt validate, because the & isn't escaped.

> & did not start a character reference. (& probably should have been escaped as &.)
>
> > /api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false">

so i did the obvious and escaped the &.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;sensor=false"></script>
```

but now it doesn't work properly, the map shows up, but it wont scroll, zoom, etc...

question:

> How do i properly make this valid html without everything breaking?

Comment: What issue is the "invalid" HTML causing?

Comment: well, i've been given the task to make sure the entire website is valid html, it's not breaking anything because of not being valid, but the fact that it's not valid is the issue itself.

Comment: I would suggest to leave it as it is. There is no syntax issue in the first way you suggested. Even the google example is similar

Comment: If this is a commercial application that you've been asked to check, why is there no API key?

Comment: You no longer need to specify the `sensor` argument when loading the map API.  So you can save yourself any headache simply by removing it!  See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Troubleshooting _"Note: The sensor parameter is no longer required."_

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates a map that doesn't work with &amp; in the API include.  [It works for me](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB_frozen.html?filename=VoterDistricts_random.xml).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither the `sensor=false` nor the `v=v3.exp` are required (sensor is no longer required, v3.exp is served by default with the free API), change your include to:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

[This Google Maps Javascript API v3 page works](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB_frozen.html?filename=VoterDistricts_random.xml) and [validates as XHTML Strict](https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2Fv3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB_frozen.html%3Ffilename%3DVoterDistricts_random.xml;accept=text%2Fhtml%2Capplication%2Fxhtml%2Bxml%2Capplication%2Fxml%3Bq%3D0.9%2Cimage%2Fwebp%2C%2A%2F%2A%3Bq%3D0.8;accept-language=en-US%2Cen%3Bq%3D0.8) with `&amp;` in the include.

Comment: welp, getting rid of the sensor did exactly what i needed in this case, now it's both valid HTML and the map still works flawlessly, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because there is a validation issue somewhere else in the page. Your modification is correct as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979549/google-maps-api-javascript-tag-not-validating). Check the other references and html script for more validation errors.

Comment: If the API is not working, I don't think the map will display. The issues in your map could be more due to the css of the map canvas more than anything. But cant tell for sure without seeing the code.